# Elm: Decoding a nested array of objects with elm-decode-pipeline

Tags: json, decode, elm

I am struggling to convert a JSON response from OpenWeatherMap using NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline.  I have managed to decode nested objects within the JSON, but I cannot do the same for an array of objects

I've included the code I currently have.  It compiles but in fails when run with `FetchWeather Err BadPayload ...`

**JSON**

```json
{
     "weather":[{"id":804}],
     "main":{"temp":289.5},
}
```

**CODE**

```elm
type alias OpenWeatherResponse =
  { main: MainResult
  , weather: WeatherResult
  }

type alias MainResult =
  { temp: Float }

type alias ConditionResult =
  { code: Int }

decodeOpenWeatherResponse : Decoder OpenWeatherResponse
decodeOpenWeatherResponse =
    decode OpenWeatherResponse
        |> required "main" decodeMain
        |> required "weather" decodeConditions

decodeMain : Decoder MainResult
decodeMain =
    decode MainResult
        |> required "temp" float

decodeConditions : Decoder ConditionResult
decodeConditions =
     decode ConditionResult
        |> required "id" int -- This is clearly wrong --
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Json.Decode.list : Decoder a -> Decoder (List a)` to make a parser of a list from a parser of an item.

```
decodeConditions : Decoder (List ConditionResult)
decodeConditions =
    Json.Decode.list decodeCondition

decodeCondition : Decoder ConditionResult
decodeCondition =
    decode ConditionResult
        |> required "id" int
```

Or, you can make it look like a part of the pipeline:

```
decodeConditions : Decoder (List ConditionResult)
decodeConditions=
    decode ConditionResult
        |> required "id" int
        |> Json.Decode.list
```

Also, the response type has to have a list:

```
type alias OpenWeatherResponse =
  { main : MainResult
  , weather : List ConditionResult
  }
```

If you just want the first item of the `weather` array, you can use `Json.Decode.index : Int -> Decoder a -> Decoder a`:

```
decodeConditions : Decoder ConditionResult
decodeConditions =
     decode ConditionResult
        |> required "id" int
        |> Json.Decode.index 0
```